# use integer as comment char as integer with read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, io

I have data that looks like:

```
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
66,1970,1,100,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
66,1970,1,100,
```

No, I would like to exclude / skip reading row ignore all data which start with `66`.

How do I assemble my pd.read_csv?

```
data = """
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
66,1970,1,100,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
306,1970,
66,1970,1,100,
"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None, dtype={1 : str },  comment='6',)
```

But this skips all after `30`:

```
     0
0   30
1   30
2   30
3   30
4   30
5   30
6   30
7   30
8   30
9   30
10  30
11  30
```

Answer (score 1):

first load the dataframe  ( and declare the column)

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=[0,1,2,3] ,header=None,dtype={0 : str })
```

second step use regex to remove string starting with 66

```
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('^66')]
df
```